# php loop through domain list file and remove subdomains

Tags: php, readfile

I want to list a "file" with `sub.domain.tld` names, remove sub and list `uniqe domain.tld` names

I can't figure out why my output ($list) doubles the last line "voorbeeld.nl"

```
<?php
$lines=file("list.txt");

$list = array();  //create empty array
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        $line_explode = explode('.', $line);
        array_push($list, $line_explode[1] .'.'. $line_explode[2]);

}
echo "<br>-----------<br>"; 
foreach(array_unique($list) as $Resuld){ 
    echo '>' . $Resuld .'< <br>'; 
}
echo "-----------<br>"; ? >
```

list.txt:

```
sub1.example.nl
sub2.example.nl
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
sub3.example.com
sub1.voorbeeld.nl
sub2.voorbeeld.nl
sub3.voorbeeld.nl
```

result:

```
-----------
>example.nl < 
>example.com < 
>voorbeeld.nl < 
>voorbeeld.nl< 
-----------
```

Comment: If your result is precise, the last line has no trailing blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check link https://eval.in/686821  This is working fine

In your output, I can see an extra space. Most probably, that can be reson for your issue.

```
>voorbeeld.nl < 
>voorbeeld.nl<
```

Modify your code as follows

```
array_push($list, trim($line_explode[1]) .'.'. trim($line_explode[2]));
```

Comment: your rite this woks , now relapse your aray with  a file and it does not :(

Comment: Check content of your file

Comment: Updated answer !!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$list[$line_explode[1] .'.'. $line_explode[2]]=$line_explode[1] .'.'. $line_explode[2];
```

in stead of this

```
array_push($list, $line_explode[1] .'.'. $line_explode[2]);
```